# Android получить метаданные изображения

Tags: java, android, metadata

Как можно получить метаданные(время создания и размер файла) png изоражения? По возможности без подключения сторонних бибилиотек.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Размер файла

```
file.length()
```

Даты создания через родные классы не получить вроде. Только последнего изменения

```
file.lastModified()
```

Если сильо надо - можно хранить в дате модификации дату "создания". Когда открываете файл - запоминаете в отдельную переменную время модификации. Перед закрытием вписываете запомненную дату с помощью `setLastModified`